# Как реализовать замену фона родительского блока по наведению курсора на ссылку?

Tags: jquery, css

[image: Пример]
Как можно корректно реализовать смену фона у родительского блока (отмечен пунктирными линиями) при наведении курсора на синий круг?
Напрашивается сделать общий фон картинку с отдельными участками измененных областей для режима hover родительских блоков.
Как корректно сделать привязку кругов и родительских фонов?

Смысл в том, что при наведении на фоне появляются изменения.
Разметка изначальная:

```html
<ul class="picture">
  <li class="block-link1">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="icon-link" src="" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="block-link2">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="icon-link" src="" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="block-link2">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="icon-link" src="" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Добавьте ваш код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант на css

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.picture {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.picture-link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  background: #00f;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 10px;
  transition: .3s;
}

.picture-link:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
}

.picture-link:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}

.picture-link:hover {
  background: tomato;
}

.picture-image-1 {
  background-image: url(http://frederictoncrc.com/new/img/slider/background1.jpg);
}

.picture-image-2 {
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTZ4xNwMCTfSlR9FTehxEV51nJ4SNOKwfURcQj_2_iueAXX0u2b);
}

.picture-image-3 {
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcToVzpCM0crGK5g9ErwxtlHwv9RAUBwcjWHYjmVGfYf36D4zNotBA);
}

.picture-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-color: #ccc;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}

.picture-image-1,
.picture-link:nth-of-type(1):hover~.picture-image-1,
.picture-link:nth-of-type(2):hover~.picture-image-2,
.picture-link:nth-of-type(3):hover~.picture-image-3 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="picture">
  <a href="#" class="picture-link">link 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="picture-link">link 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="picture-link">link 3</a>
  <div class="picture-image picture-image-1"></div>
  <div class="picture-image picture-image-2"></div>
  <div class="picture-image picture-image-3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вопрос: .picture-link:nth-of-type(1):hover~.picture-image-1 это работает я так понимаю не на всех браузерах?

Comment: '~' работает по ie7 включительно; nth-of-type(1) - по ie9 включительно. Данный пример будет работать по ie9 включительно.

Comment: Интересный приём! А в других Edge, Opera, Firefox?

Comment: Да будет работать во всех современных браузерах

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, замысел. Я так понимаю это работает только такой html конструкции? А если будет массив ul, а li в нем будут этими родительскими блоками с ссылками внутри.

Comment: правые соседи: все .picture-image на том же уровне вложенности, которые идут после .picture-link. Но т.к нам нет необходимоcти выбирать все изображения при наведении на ссылку - добавляем nth-of-type, чтобы конкретно указать, что мы должны выбрать при наведении. Да если ссылки поместить в блок (прямой родитель), а изображения будут находится вне этого родителя - этот вариант работать не будет.

Comment: @soledar10 оригинально...

Comment: @Agestor Вариант с ul li - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/19dsge7x/2/

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то вам следует использовать `.hover()`:

```js
$(".link").hover(
  e => {
    $(e.target).parent().css("background-color", "yellow");
  },
  e => {
    $(e.target).parent().css("background-color", "black");
  });
```

```css
.dynamic-background {
  background-color: black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.link {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dynamic-background">
  <a class="link">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю! А в таком варианте я могу использовать единую картинку со всеми вариациями фона, а вместо "background-color", "black" будет указываться положение нужного участка? Вот этот вариант нужен (использование изображения карты). Не могу найти как это делается, хотя часто вижу, что используют этот приём.

Comment: @Agestor добавьте ваш код, включая стили и ссылки на требуемые картинки

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, метод (часть кода) я потом готовый шаблон включу в вопрос, просто это в фотошопе нужно карты рисовать.